# Stuck when studying java from learnjavaonline

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

```
class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public void printFullName() {
        System.out.println (this.firstName+" "+this.lastName);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[] {
            new Student("Morgan", "Freeman"),
            new Student("Brad", "Pitt"),
            new Student("Kevin", "Spacey")
        };
        for (Student s : students) {
            s.printFullName();
        }
    }
}
```

I was learning java from learnjavaonline and this is the answer for one of the exercises. In their website the code runs without anyproblem, but when I ran in VScode (Java extension pack was installed and so was the latest version of Java) it returned me with the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> at Main.main(Student.java:15)

So can someone help me by pointing out what is the problem?

Comment: Try to change class name from `Main` to other name

Comment: Seeing as `Main` is the public class, the file should be named `Main.java`, not `Student.java`.

Comment: @lucumt I changed both the class **Main** and file name (they said the class that runs the code and file name must be exactly the same) but it didn't work, returning the same error

Comment: Which is line 15?

Comment: @SteveSmith it's `public static void main(String[] args) {`

Comment: It compiles and works for me if the file is called Main.java.

Comment: @SteveSmith yes and so did it in the learnjavaonline website, but the error keeps on going in my vscode

Comment: it works if file name is Main.java

Comment: @PrashantBhardwaj my file's name is Main.java yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is perfectly fine. Just rename the file as Main.java and use some other IDE. I feel this might be some setting issue with VSCode. You have to resolve all workspace errors and make sure there is only one `main(String args[])` function in your file.I too faced problem compiling a java file using java extension pack, it always showed build error but when click proceed it works. I strongly recommend you try eclipse. Or try using command line.

- Go to the folder location where you file is located.
- type `javac Main.java`
- It will compile successfully. To run use `java -c . Main`
- Make sure java is in you system path variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I run it with `Netbeans`, it returned with another error, but when I add `package main;` to the start of the code it worked.

Comment: Actually If you don't provide any package in java file, it is automatically assigned to default package. Maybe its the IDE Netbeans enforcing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two Files named Student.java and Main.java with the corresponding Code in it. Then you have to compile both Files. And last you can run the Main.class.

Comment: You don't neccessarily need 2 files; it works with only 1, which is what OP has.